# Sum of binomial coefficient equation

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to show the following equation

[image]

using binomial expansion but it's not getting me anywhere.
How should I set it up?

I've tried expanding $(2+2)^{n}$ and using the fact that

[image]

but it's not quite right. Any hints?

Comment: This is sort of a trick question. Note that the $4^n$ on the LHS doesn't depend on $k$ at all so you can factor it out.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan do you have a bit more to give? Still not getting quite there.

Comment: Have you done the factoring out? What are you left with? Do you recognize anything that you can use the binomial theorem on?

Comment: I have simply put the 4^n outside the sum sign on the LHS but where that exacly gets me I'm not sure. Maybe I could use the fact $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} = 2^{n}$ ?

Comment: Factor out the $4^n$, then use the binomial expansion formula on each side of the equation. This gives you your answer

Comment: @EodEnaj Yes, you can use that.

Comment: Please don't make questions rely on images like this. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121. You can find a tutorial and reference for formatting math on this site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020).

Comment: My suggestion: evaluate both sides and show they both equal the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noting that the $4^n$ can be factored out of the left sum, we have that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \, 4^n &= 4^n \, \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \\[2mm]
&= 4^n \cdot 2^n \\[2mm]
&= 8^n \\[2mm]
&= (1+7)^n \\[2mm]
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \, 7^k
\end{align}$$